# Countdown-timer: how to add years?

Tags: javascript

Im am referring to this simple countdown timer:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

The different variables are defined like this:

```
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

But in case I want e.g. to add the number of years I just cannot write something like

```
  var years = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 365);
```

OK, it works with the years. But then, I will have to reduce the number of days somehow. Cause otherwise, I might get results like 1 year, 499 days instead of 2 years 134 days.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you're doing for the other numbers, use modulo to determine how many days are left over *after* years have been taken away, via `% 365`:

```
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) % 365;
```